# How to create a macros to navigate to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return to the macros page; however, I receive a runtime error.

```
Sub OpenMenu()

    Sheets("Macros").Select

Dim PS As Positions

    #If VBA6 Then
        Dim HO As cstFormHorizontalPosition
        Dim VO As cstFormVerticalPosition
    #Else
        Dim HO As Long
        Dim VO As Long
    #End If


    HO = cstFhpFormLeftCellLeft '   set these to how you want the form positioned relative to AnchorCell
    VO = cstFvpFormBottomCellCenter '   set these to how you want the form positioned relative to AnchorCell


    '
    ' Call PositionForm to determine the correct positions
    '
    PS = PositionForm(WhatForm:=frmSelectReport, AnchorRange:=Range("B1"), HorizOrientation:=HO, VertOrientation:=VO)
    frmSelectReport.Top = PS.FrmTop   ' set the Top position of the form
    frmSelectReport.Left = PS.FrmLeft ' set the Left position of the form
    frmSelectReport.Show

End Sub
```

Error appears in `PS = PositionForm(WhatForm:=frmSelectReport, AnchorRange:=Range("B1"), HorizOrientation:=HO, VertOrientation:=VO)`

Comment: What is the error?